# Backslash Discrepancy between Regex Constructor and Literals

Tags: javascript, regex, constructor, literals

The title sums it up. I came across an odd discrepancy in backslash escaping between regular expression literals and constructor functions with `new RegExp()`, and I was curious about what's behind it.

I was trying to escape a parenthesis `(` inside a constructor, like so:

```
var search = new RegExp('/(', 'g');
var result = "(test)".match(search);
```

But this kept returning an error. The match worked fine inside a literal `/\(/g;`, but inside the constructor I ended up having to do something like this:

```
search = new RegExp('\\(', 'g');
```

Can someone please explain to me why an escaping backslash requires an escaping backslash itself in a constructor, but not a literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the backslash is a special character in both the context of a regexp, and the context of a string literal.  You have to get past the string literal's special usage before the regexp parser can see it and apply its own special rules.

Comment: Thanks, Paul! That does actually make sense.

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE If pattern is a StringLiteral, the usual escape sequence substitutions are performed before the String is processed by RegExp. If pattern must contain an escape sequence to be recognised by RegExp, any backslash \ characters must be escaped within the StringLiteral to prevent them being removed when the contents of the StringLiteral are formed.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.4.1